# Export bacpac to a Azure storage account using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to create a powershell script to backup a SQL database on Azure to a storage account as below,

```
$exportRequest = New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport -ResourceGroupName 
$ResourceGroupName -ServerName $ServerName `
-DatabaseName $DatabaseName -StorageKeytype $StorageKeytype -StorageKey 
$StorageKey -StorageUri $BacpacUri `
-AdministratorLogin $creds.UserName -AdministratorLoginPassword $creds.Password
```

This is the document i'm following,

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export
```

I assume the following,

```
$ResourceGroupName - my azure resource group
$ServerName - db server name
$DatabaseName - database name
**$StorageKeytype - NOT SURE WHAT VALUE SHOULD BE PLACED HERE**
**$StorageKey - I'm hoping this is one of the access keys under the azure storage account**
$BacpacUri - Azure storage account bacpac URI path
```

Please advice what parameters need to passed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please advice what parameters need to passed here.

- **StorageKey** : Specifies the access key for the storage account.
- **StorageKeyType**: 
  Specifies the type of access key for the storage account.

  The acceptable values for this parameter are:

  `StorageAccessKey`. This value uses a storage account key.

  `SharedAccessKey`. This value uses a Shared Access Signature (SAS) key.

For more details, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.sql/new-azurermsqldatabaseexport?view=azurermps-6.8.1).

Comment: Thank you for replying Joy. Can you give me one example of what should be the value for the StorageKey Type. From my azure storage account, where should i be looking for this value?

Comment: @AryanM Just use `StorageAccessKey` for the value of `StorageKeyType`.

Comment: I have updated my question with the snapshot of the AccessKey for my storage account on Azure. So, i suppose that will be my storageKey. If yes, what will be my storageKey Type?

Comment: @AryanM The `StorageKeyType`  just allows two values, in this case, specify the `StorageKeyType` with `StorageAccessKey`. Also, i recommend you to hide the sensitive information of your storage account in your question.

Comment: Thank you mate. Got it now.

Comment: @AryanM Glad to help you, if it is convenient, you could try my solution in your another post, it works on my side.

Comment: Sure mate. I will try that